# Displaying Go App In The Browser

Tags: json, go

I wrote an app that makes a request to an API and gets a JSON response. When I run the app it displays the json in the terminal.

```
go run main.go
```

I want to make this run in the browser and I found this, which allowed me to print a string to the browser.

```
     func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       fmt.Fprintf(w, "This is a string")
   }
```

Then in `main`

```
http.HandleFunc("/", handler) 
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", nil))
```

Now that I have a string being printed to the screen and I have a json response coming from the api I am using, how can I add the json response to the browser instead of the string?

Would it be best to put the response into a string then just bring it to the browser?

Currently I am printing the json response to the terminal like this,

```
type Payload struct {
        Page    int
        Results []Data 
}

type Data struct {
        PosterPath       string  `json:"poster_path"`
        Adult            bool    `json:"adult"`
        Overview         string  `json:"overview"`
        ReleaseDate      string  `json:"release_date"`
        GenreIds         []int   `json:"genre_ids"`
        Id               int     `json:"id"`
        OriginalTitle    string  `json:"original_title"`
        OriginalLanguage string  `json:"original_language"`
        Title            string  `json:"title"`
        BackdropPath     string  `json:"backdrop_path"`
        Popularity       float64 `json:"popularity"`
        VoteCount        int     `json:"vote_count"`
        Video            bool    `json:"video"`
        VoteAverage      float64 `json:"vote_average"`
}
```

Then inside `main()` I do this,

```
    for i := 0; i < len(p.Results); i++ {
            fmt.Println(
            ImgUrl+p.Results[i].PosterPath, "\n", p.Results[i].Adult,
            p.Results[i].Overview, "\n", p.Results[i].ReleaseDate,
            p.Results[i].GenreIds, "\n", p.Results[i].Id,
            p.Results[i].OriginalTitle, "\n", p.Results[i].OriginalLanguage,
            p.Results[i].Title, "\n", ImgUrl+p.Results[i].BackdropPath,
            p.Results[i].Popularity, "\n", p.Results[i].VoteCount,
            p.Results[i].Video, "\n", p.Results[i].VoteAverage,
            )
```

What would be the Go way to do this for building web applications? My end goal here is to take user input and recreate my api call based on the information they provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with directly sending the response from the API to your users then use [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy). You can check if the api request was successful before relaying it to the users and send an error if it did not.

Some APIs send information in headers like how you are doing with the rate limiting. So you can check headers as well before relaying.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") // your request to the api

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/javascript")

    if err == nil && resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        io.Copy(w, resp.Body)
    } else {
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(err)
    }
}
```

This avoids making any new allocations on your app.

If you want to send your clients html as stated in comments, use the [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package.

You can of course prepare a html string manually and send it to the clients. But I think its obvious that using templates makes the code cleaner and maintainable. It also provides autoescaping.

For example following would render the `Overview` section of each of your `Results` from the `Payload` `p`

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Make your api call and prepare the `Payload` object (from your example in the question)

    for i := 0; i < len(p.Results); i++ {
       fmt.Println(p.Results[i].Overview) // Prints to your terminal
    }

    // Following sends same information as above to the browser as html

    t, err := template.New("foo").Parse(`
      {{define "T"}}
        <html><ul>{{range .Results}}<li>{{.Overview}}</li>{{end}}</ul></html>
      {{end}}`)
    err = t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "T", p) // This writes the client response
}
```

Comment: What do you mean am if I am fine with it? Are there downsides?

Comment: I thought maybe you want to strip out content that are not useful to your clients. If API returns errors in case of rate limiting etc, those errors will be sent directly to clients.

Comment: Gotcha. Could you give me a few ways to do this? So I can try a few and learn this better?

Comment: also the response is in json. How can I parse that and wrap it in html if I make the request to the api and directly post it to the page?

Comment: If you want to render html checkout template package https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

Comment: Ya I have seen that. Would you mind giving me an example of it using my current situation?

Comment: Or how about how can I push my data to a string then just call that string in my handler?

Comment: I added an example usage of the template package. It doesn't really matter where your data comes from. Since you already have a Payload type and a `p` instance you can easily use the template package for this.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I am so confused by what your showing me here. I dont even understand where that is supposed to go? So you are saying just add that block of code to my handle function?\

Comment: yes that goes in the handler function. I think going through the documentation of [template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package would help you understand

Comment: Yes I have read it. I cant get a solid understanding based on my circumstances. If it makes perfect sense to you would you mind adding it to your example so I can see exactly what you are saying?

Comment: It appears you are showing me code from the documentation. Which I have read. My problem is not that I can not read the docs, my problem is I do not understand how to properly write this function to get it to work.

Comment: The code I posted is specific to your example. I used the variables and structures that you showed in the question. They were not just blindly copied from the documentation. Its a lot disappointing that you think so. I have put my best effort to help you. I updated the code putting it inside the handler function. I am sorry but I think I have been the best help I possibly can. Hope this will help you with your app.